# python socket connection not returning any information

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to receive information from a websocket on a local nodejs server with a python script. The server originally sent the data to a webpage to be viewed and works when viewed on the page but when I connect using python I don't get anything.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 3000))
message = s.recv(1024)
print(message.decode("utf-8"))
```

If I remove `.decode("utf-8")` then I get `b''` returned, I am just having trouble figuring out what else I need to change here to make this work or find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: A WebSocket is something rather different from a plain socket as provided by your operating system.  You'd need some specific module to handle the additional layers of protocol involved in a WebSocket connection - sorry, I don't have any recommendation for one as I've never needed it myself.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you, I was kind of able to get websocket-client working.